# How to get related data with linq?

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a **Personnel** table and **PersonnelDrivingLicense** table. There is more than one record in the PersonnelDrivingLicense table related to one Personnel.

I tried to get Personnel and PersonnelDrivingLicense data with linq but I am getting 2 record instead 1.

Here is my linq query:

```
from p in Personnel
join pdl in PersonnelDrivingLicense on p.Id equals pdl.PersonnelId
select new Personnel
{
    Id = p.Id,
    PersonnelDrivingLicense = new List<PersonnelDrivingLicense>
    {
        new PersonnelDrivinLicense
        {
             Id = pdl.Id,
             DrivingLicenseClass = pdl.DrivingLicenseClass
        }
    }
}
```

This linq returns below result:

```
Id: 1,
PersonnelDrivingLicense:
    Id: 1,
    DrivingLicenseClass: B

Id: 1,
PersonnelDrivingLicense:
    Id: 2,
    DrivingLicenseClass: C
```

The correct result should be below:

```
Id: 1,
PersonnelDrivingLicense:
    Id: 1,
    DrivingLicenseClass: B

    Id: 2,
    DrivingLicenseClass: C
```

How can I get desired result above?
How should I write correct linq query?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have relation between personnel and drivingLicence tables (navigation property for collection of driving licenses): `context.Personnel.Include(p => p.DrivingLicenses).ToList()`

Comment: (Inner) Join generates a cross-product result, basically 1 row per every join-key match. Thats why you see "duplicated" results. By grouping the rows you would solve this. Furthermore, if you are using entity frameworks there are easier ways to do this depending on your models relations. Can you add the entity models into your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should group the returned Personnel objects by Id. Try this:

```
from p in Personnel
join pdl in PersonnelDrivingLicense on p.Id equals pdl.PersonnelId
group p by p.Id into g
select new Personnel
{
    Id = g.Key,
    PersonnelDrivingLicense = g.Select(x => x.PersonnelDrivingLicense).ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a one-to-many or a many-to-many relationship, and you want an item with their sub-items, you should use GroupJoin instead of Join.

In you case, you have `Personnel` and `PersonnelDrivingLicenses`, probably a one-to-many relation: every `Personnel` object has zero or more `PersonnelDrivingLicences`. Every `PersonnelDrivingLicence` belongs to exactly one `Personnel` object, namely the `Personnel` that the foreign key `PersonnelId` refers to.

Apparently you want a sequence of `Personnel` objects, each `Personnel` object with a list of his/her `PersonnelDrivingLicenses`.

```
// GroupJoin Personnel with PersonnelDrivingLicenses
var personnelWithTheirDrivingLicenses = myDbContext.Personnel
    .GroupJoin(myDbDcontext.PersonnelDrivingLicenses,

    // from every personnel object take the Id,
    personnel => personnel.Id,
    // from every driving license take the PersonnelId
    personnelDrivingLicence => personnelDrivingLicence.PersonnelId,

    // Take the Personnel, with all his matching driving licenses to make a new:
    (personnel, drivingLicenses) => new
    {
        // for optimal efficiency, Select only the properties you plan to use:
        Id = personnel.Id,
        Name = personnel.Name,
        ...

        DrivingLicenses = drivingLicenses
            .Where(drivingLicense => ...) // only if you don't want all his DrivingLicenses
            .Select(drivingLicense => new
            {
                // again, select only the properties you plan to use:
                Id = drivingLicense.Id,
                Type = drivingLicense.Type,
                ...

                // not needed, you already know the value:
                // PersonnelId = drivingLicense.PersonnelId,
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```